# Ical not supported calendar message

Tags: outlook, format, icalendar, hotmail

In hotmail i've the following icalendar that not accepted by hotmail, what is the reason?
Error: Not supported calendar message:

BEGIN:VCALENDAR

PRODID:-//EcosAgile//V1//EN

VERSION:2.0

METHOD:REQUEST

BEGIN:VTIMEZONE

TZID:W. Europe Standard Time

BEGIN:STANDARD

DTSTART:16010101T030000

TZOFFSETFROM:+0200

TZOFFSETTO:+0100

RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10

END:STANDARD

BEGIN:DAYLIGHT

DTSTART:16010101T020000

TZOFFSETFROM:+0100

TZOFFSETTO:+0200

RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3

END:DAYLIGHT

END:VTIMEZONE

BEGIN:VEVENT

UID:96d3845d-4cc4-4498-bb4d-7a8503b597e6

SUMMARY:Approvazione richiesta Smart working Tomi, Ivio per il 15/09/2017 Buongiorno Tomi, Ivio
le confermiamo che è stata approvata la seguente richiesta:
Codice Richiesta: 151

Causale: Smart working

Data/Ora Inizio: 15/09/2017 - 18:00

Data/Ora Fine: 15/09/2017 - 20:00

LOCATION:

CLASS:BUSY

CATEGORIES:general

CREATED:20170929T143600Z

DTSTAMP:20170929T143600Z

LAST-MODIFIED:20170929T143600Z

X-XM-SHARE:0

DTSTART;TZID=W. Europe Standard Time:20170915T160000Z

DTEND;TZID=W. Europe Standard Time:20170915T180000Z

SEQUENCE:0

ATTENDEE;RSVP=FALSE:MAILTO:valta@agile.com

ORGANIZER:MAILTO:AgileNotifiche@agile.com

END:VEVENT

END:VCALENDAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you put it through the various ics validators, you'll find a bunch of errors.  They work differently and do not all pick up everything:

https://icalendar.org/validator.html
Errors
    Invalid DTSTART value, The 'TZID' property parameter MUST NOT be applied to DATE-TIME properties whose time values are specified in UTC. near line # 39Reference: 3.3.5. Date-Time
    Invalid DTEND value, The 'TZID' property parameter MUST NOT be applied to DATE-TIME properties whose time values are specified in UTC. near line # 39Reference: 3.3.5. Date-Time

http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com:

! Character [,] in property [SUMMARY] should be escaped
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.3.11
! Character [,] in property [SUMMARY] should be escaped
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.3.11
! Invalid name [CAUSALE]. Experimental properties must have the following prefix: X-
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.8.2
! Invalid name [DATA/ORA INIZIO]. Experimental properties must have the following prefix: X-
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.8.2
! Invalid name [DATA/ORA FINE]. Experimental properties must have the following prefix: X-
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.8.2